# Reading artist metadata from DBus in lua script - weird output

Tags: lua, dbus, audio-player

I'm trying to reading in `DBus metadata` from `nuvolaplayer` in a Lua script. The (track) title and album fields display as expect, but the artist data appears oddly:

```
lgi.rec 0x7f9ee8005c90:GLib.Variant Underwater Dub  Dictionary
```

Where `"Sly & Robbie"` is expected in place of `"lgi.rec 0x7f9ee8005c90:GLib.Variant"`.

When I look at the value using `d-feet`, I can see that the `xesam:artist` field differs from the others in being surrounded by []s.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
local lgi = require 'lgi'
local Gio = lgi.require 'Gio'
local core = require 'lgi.core'
local GLib = lgi.require 'GLib'
local type,unpack = type,unpack
local bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION)

local ret,err = bus:call(
    "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.nuvolaplayer",
    --"org.gnome.Rhythmbox3",
    "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
    "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
    "GetAll",
    GLib.Variant.new_tuple(
    {
        GLib.Variant("s","org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player")
    }, 1),
    nil,
    Gio.DBusConnectionFlags.NONE,
    -1, -- Timeout
    nil, -- Cancellable
    function(conn, res)
        local ret, err = bus:call_finish(res)
        print("here",err)

        local returnValue1, returnValue2 = unpack(ret.value)
        if not err then
            print("META", returnValue1.Metadata["xesam:artist"],
                returnValue1.Metadata["xesam:album"],
                returnValue1.Metadata["xesam:title"])
        end
    end
)

local main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop:run()
```

Comment: Can you post the d-feet output and the signature of the method?

Comment: For some reason d-feet is acting oddly today. Now when I try to double-click on the "Dict of {String,Variant} Metadata" entry it changes into a "Boolean CanSeek" - it didn't do that yesterday. So I'm not sure how to get the d-feet output now....

Answer (score 1):

The field [xesam:artist](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/metadata/#index6h4) is a list/array of strings (artists). Maybe Lua needs special handling of this type for printing, for example iterate the array and extract plain strings from it.